# How to generate yii2 api documentation?plese give steps for it?

Tags: yii, yii2

While I am creating project API Doc. It causes more error. I have refereed [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-apidoc-index.html).

Comment: Question is very poorly asked. Most of the edits were grammatical.

Answer (score 0):

as  showed  in guide http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-apidoc-index.html#usage

you must invoke the command eg ( for apidoc api )

for windows  enviroment

```
 .\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-apidoc\apidoc.bat api  ./docs/api
```

or

for linux enviroment

```
 ./vendor/yiisoft/yii2-apidoc/apidoc api  ./docs/api
```

these command return the doc result in the directory  `./docs/api`

Comment: I am using Linux while running  above command it gives  Error: Uninitialized string offset: 0